# Session-based authorization in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication

I have a Spring-MVC (Spring 4) based server that provides a REST service to an outside client (IE, I do not have a view hosted on my server). A requirement has been added to add a login service to the REST which authenticates against a backend server.

My question is: How do I add a login request to the REST server in such a way that every request that goes to the server first goes through a check to see if the user has authenticated and if there is an active session, and returns an error if this is not the case? Preferably, this should be transparent to other requests, and should not require a code change at the other @RestController based classes.

Thanks

Comment: You could use Spring Security framework.